# read unix config file from CLI

Tags: command-line, unix

I need to access a configuration file from a Makefile, and thus seek for a *short-readable-maintanable* way of doing. The file is a python 
[`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) compliant file.

```
#foo.cfg
[foo]
bar = baz
```

I use this python oneliner which I found cumbersome

```
python -c "import ConfigParser; config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(); config.read('foo.cfg');print config.get('foo','bar')"
```

Since it is the same format used in git config files, I noticed that `git config -f foo.cfg --get foo.bar` might do the job, but (1) my section name got an underscore, which is not supported by `git-config`, and (2) it adds an heavy build dependancy for weird and accessory purpose .

I have seen this format used so many time that I think it might exists a better way.

My questions are:

- does this config format get a name ? (which might help for web search)
- is there any standard CLI tools (as simple as `git-config`) to read these files?

Comment: That looks like an "INI file" format. You may want to write a wrapper-function (or script) so that you can simplify your Makefile commands. See http://ajdiaz.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/bash-ini-parser/